# How can I use a function of cbindlist in R to merge multiple cvs files stored in my computer?

Tags: r

Here are the codes that I'm using:

```
library(data.table)

# Get a List of all files in directory named with a key word, say all `.csv` files
filenames <- list.files("D:/FILES/yahoo cvs", pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)

# read and row bind all data sets
data <- rbindlist(lapply(filenames,fread))
```

It works very well, but I want to combine files with cbindlist. I just simply changed rbindlist to cbindlist and it didn't work. How can I do this?

```
File AAA                    

    C1  C2          
R1  10  20          
R2  30  40          

File BBB                    

    C1  C2          
R1  50  60          
R2  80  70          



Combined new file                   


    AAA.C1  AAA.C2      BBB.C1  BBB.C2
R1   10      20     R1    50      60
R2   30      40     R2    80      70
```

Comment: `do.call(cbind, lapply(filenames,fread))` ?

Comment: Oh thank you Ronak.

Comment: Hey Ronak, can I add a row on the top as each file's name? If AAA file has columns called A, B, C, then I want to have a new row on the top named AAA, AAA, AAA. Is it possible?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand, can you add an example ?

Comment: I added an example above. Please check this

Comment: You cannot have two headers in an R dataframe.

Comment: @RonakShah, I edited the example. Is it possible then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `lapply` if you use `sapply` with `simplify = FALSE` it will attach the filenames to the column names when you `cbind`.

```
data <- do.call(cbind, sapply(filenames,data.table::fread, simplify = FALSE))
```

Comment: is there a way where all the dataframe can go one after other vertically down instead of side by side as asked in this question. Like I have list which i want to put in a data table

Comment: You can use `data <- do.call(rbind, .......)` @PesKchan